# How to use pointer to bidimensional array C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How do I edit a value in an array with pointer in C?

```
int *pointer;
int array[3][1];
```

I tried this:

```
int *Pointer
int array[2][2];
Pointer[1][1]= 6;
```

but when compiling, I get a segmentation fault error. What to do?

Comment: Just point at it. `pointer = &array[2][0]`

Comment: Re “when compiling”: The code `int *Pointer` / `int array[2][2];` / `Pointer[1][1]= 6;` does not get a segmentation error because it does not compile, for multiple reasons. When asking about code in Stack Overflow, copy and paste **exact** code. Simple typographical mistakes can prevent readers from knowing what the problems really are and make everybody unable to help you. Errors like that are also likely to get you down votes, as they make the question unclear and also can make answers unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can *access* any given element with this syntax: `array[x][y]`.

By the same token, you can assign your pointer to any element with this syntax: `p = &array[x][y]`.

---

In C, you can often treat arrays and pointers as "equivalent".  Here is a good explanation:

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

However, you *cannot* treat a simple pointer as a 2-d array.  Here's a code example:

```
/*
 * Sample output:
 *
 * array=0x7ffc463d0860
 * 1 2 3
 * 4 5 6
 * 7 8 9
 * p=0x7ffc463d0860
 * 0x7ffc463d0864:1 0x7ffc463d0868:2 0x7ffc463d086c:3
 * 0x7ffc463d0870:4 0x7ffc463d0874:5 0x7ffc463d0878:6
 * 0x7ffc463d087c:7 0x7ffc463d0880:8 0x7ffc463d0884:9
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j, *p;
  int array[3][3] = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
  };

  // Dereference 2-D array using indexes
  printf("array=%p\n", array);
  for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < 3; j++)
      printf ("%d ", array[i][j]);
    printf ("\n");
  }

  // Dereference 2-D array using pointer
  p = &array[0][0];
  printf("p=%p\n", p);
  for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < 3; j++)
      printf ("%p:%d ", p, *p++);
    printf ("\n");
  }

  /* Compile error: subscripted value p[0][0] is neither array nor pointer nor vector
      p = &array[0][0];
      printf("p=%p, p[0]=%p, p[0][0]=%p\n", p, &p[0], &p[0][0]);
   */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the asterisk

Comment: I used what you suggested, and worked, the pointer is pointing to the first memory slot of the array, but i cannot edit it:
 pointer[1][2]=69;
the program simply crashes

Answer (score 1):

Given some array `int Array[Rows][Columns]`, to make a pointer to a specific element `Array[r][c]` in it, define `int *Pointer = &Array[r][c];`.

Then you may access that element using `*Pointer` in an expression, including assigning to `*Pointer` to assign values to that element. You may also refer to the element as `Pointer[0]`, and you may refer to other elements in the same row as `Pointer[y]`, where `y` is such that 0 ≤ `y+c` < `Columns`, *i.e.*, `Pointer[y]` remains in the same row of the array.

You may also use `Pointer[y]` to refer to elements of the array in other rows as long as none of the language lawyers see you doing it. (In other words, this behavior is technically not defined by the C standard, but many compilers allow it.) *E.g.*, after `Pointer = &Array[r][c];`, `Pointer[2*Columns+3]` will refer to the element `Array[r+2][c+3]`.

To make a pointer you can use to access elements of the array using two dimensions, define `int (*Pointer)[Columns] = &Array[r];`.

Then `Pointer[x][y]` will refer to element `Array[r+x][y]`. In particularly, after `int (*Pointer)[Columns] = &Array[0];` or `int (*Pointer)[Columns] = Array;`, `Pointer[x][y]` and `Array[x][y]` will refer to the same element.

Comment: Not just language lawyers, but you must not let the compiler see it either... given the amount of range checking code in recent compilers...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It is a common practice in signal-processing and other software that handles matrices. Given a two-dimensional array of `foo`, one passes a subarray by passing a pointer to the `foo` at the origin of the subarray along with dimensions of the subarray and the number of columns in the containing array. So, for practical purposes, compilers need to support this. I do not have it in writing, but my recollection is Apple’s compiler developers support it.

Comment: but for that case it is still always possible to use a VLA pointer!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: If I have a `float A[100][100]` and want to pass the 50×50 subarray starting at `A[50][50]`, I would need to take `&A[50][50]` and cast it to pass it as a `float (*)[100]`. That is also not defined with pedantic interpretations of the C standard. And any solution changing APIs will not work with the large quantity of existing matrix software.

Comment: Indeed, you would have to actually pass the column 50 as an argument with a row pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the 2D-array into 1D-array to pass it to a pointer,
And then, You are ready to access array with pointer. You can use this method to pass 2D-array to a function too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[2][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = (2 * i) + j;
        }
    }
    int *Pointer = (int *)arr; // Type conversion
    /*
    &arr[0][0] = Pointer + 0
    &arr[0][1] = Pointer + 1
    &arr[1][2] = Pointer + 2
    &arr[2][2] = Pointer + 3

    Dereference Pointer to access variable behind the address
    *(Pointer + 0) = arr[0][0]
    *(Pointer + 1) = arr[0][1]
    *(Pointer + 2) = arr[1][2]
    *(Pointer + 3) = arr[2][2]

    */
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(Pointer + (2 * i) + j)); // Accessing array with pointer
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function wv_matalloc from https://www.ratrabbit.nl/ratrabbit/content/sw/matalloc/introduction , you can write the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wv_matalloc.h"
int main()
{
   double **matrix;
   int m = 3;
   int n = 4;
   // allocate m*n matrix:
   matrix = wv_matalloc(sizeof(double),0,2,m,n);

   // example of usage:
   int i,j;
   for (i=0; i<m; i++)
      for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = i*j;
   printf("2 3: %f\n",matrix[2][3]);
}
```

Compile with:

```
cc -o main main.c wv_matalloc.c
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

You never assigned a value to `Pointer` in your example. Thus, attempting to access `array` by `Pointer` invokes undefined behavior.

You need to assign `Pointer` by the address of the first element of `array` if the pointer shall be a reference:

```
Pointer = *array;
```

#### 2.

You can't use 2D notation (`p[1][1]`) for a pointer to `int`. This is a C syntax violation.

---

#### 3.

Since rows of static 2D arrays are allocated subsequent in memory, you also can count the number of array elements until the specific element of desire. You need to subtract the count by `1` since indexing start at `0`, not `1`.

How does it work?

Each row of `array` contains 2 elements. `a[1][1]` (the first element of the second row) is directly stored after the first two.

Note: This is not the best approach. But worth a note beside all other answers as *possible* solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{   
   int *Pointer;
   static int array[2][2];

   Pointer = *array;

   Pointer[2] = 6;

   printf("array[1][1] (by pointer) = %d\n", Pointer[3]);
   printf("array[1][1] (by array istelf) = %d\n", array[1][1]);
}
```

Output:

```
array[2][2] (by pointer) = 6
array[2][2] (by array istelf) = 6
```

---

Side Notes:

- To address the first element of the second row by `array[1][2]` invokes undefined behavior. You should not use this way.
- > "*but when compiling, I get a segmentation fault error.*"

Segmentation fault error do not occur at compile time. They occur at run time. It just gives you the impression because high probably your implementation immediately executes the program after compilation.